# How can I cite someone who has a nickname longer than two words?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I often want to give credit in an answer (i.e. a post) to people who have nicknames longer than one word. When I mention the user with "@", how can I make it link to the user profile by Stack Overflow?

Comment: It autocompletes to the name without spaces anywhere mentions work.

Comment: Mentions don't link.  If you're just asking how to create a link, then you create it with the normal markdown syntax.

Comment: Are you talking about using this in _comments_, or in _posts_?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I was talking about posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces.

*e.g.* to reply to "Long User Name", you'd mention `@longusername`

See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/141629) for more details, specifically (emphasis mine):

- Take the first word immediately following the @, where the word boundary is determined by a space, a character not valid in user names (such as : , / ! ?) or the end of the comment.
- Remove one trailing dot . from the resulting string if applicable (and if the string has more than two characters).
- If the remaining string ends in ' or 's, remove that piece from the string.
- The resulting string will be matched against the user name **with spaces removed**.

Comment: Thank you for the documented answer.

Comment: Note that this only applies to comments, @Billybobbonnet; the "@username" has no special significance in a regular post.

Comment: Which comment? Mine? I deleted it myself, after @JoshCaswell's clarifying comment. Why leave up incorrect information? I'm happy to be corrected, and wasn't aware that I was part of an argument. Josh had more up-to-date information than I did, he added it, and I removed the inaccurate assertion. That *is* "teamplay".

Answer (score 8):

The "@username" form has no special significance in anything other than a comment; it won't be recognized as a "mention" or specially formatted. [Paul Roub's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317823/603977), which links to [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/141629), explains how the syntax (specifically, the matching for purposes of pinging) works in comments.

In other cases, if you need to link to a user's profile, you handle it as any other link, using either markdown:

```
[Josh Caswell's profile][0]

[0]:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell
```

or, if you prefer for some strange reason, HTML:

```
<a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell">Josh Caswell's profile</a>
```

Again, there's no pinging/notification feature on Stack Exchange for "@username" other than in comments, so you should not use the "@" in the context of a regular post.

If you want to cite another user's answer, I would suggest linking to the answer itself, as I did above for Paul Roub's answer to this question.